# <c:if> jstl condition does not work

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, web, jstl

i'm **beginner** in **java ee programing** and i writing a **JSTL** condition for verify in the **session bean** if Login Status is true or false.

```
<c:choose>
  <c:if test="${Boolean.valueOf(Session.getLogStat())}">
    ${Session.getLogStat()}
  </c:if>
  <c:if test="${Boolean.valueOf(!Session.getLogStat())}">
    <a href="login">login</a>
  </c:if>
</c:choose>
```

and when i replace **if** with **when**:

```
<c:choose>
  <c:when test="${Boolean.valueOf(Session.getLogStat())}">
    ${Session.getLogStat()}
  </c:when>
  <c:when test="${Boolean.valueOf(!Session.getLogStat())}">
    <a href="login">login</a>
  </c:when>
</c:choose>
```

#### i'm sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## If your problem still persists ( you say in your answer : but the code does not work with ... )

I suggest that you intansiate your bean in a servlet . the servlet will set your parameter  in the request . then you test what you want  in your JSP .

```
public class ExampleServlet extends HttpServlet {


    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {


                Session MyObject = new Session();
                 boolean myParam=MyObject.getLogStat();  


  
  String s1 = Boolean.toString(myParam);


       try {
            

        request.setAttribute("I_WANT_TO_TEST", s1);

        RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("My.jsp");
        view.forward(request, response); 


         } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }


    }}
```

then in your JSP

```
  <% String msg2=(String)request.getAttribute("I_WANT_TO_TEST");%>
                
        <% if ( (msg2==null || msg2.isEmpty()) ) { %> 
         // WHAT YOU ARE NOT LOGED IN             
        <% } else if(msg2!=null) { %>
                        
         <% }  %>
```

Comment: thinks it work with this condition, but can i **include servlet** in other **jsp** file?

Comment: what do you mean with include servlet ?
 you want to pass parameter to it

you can call it with a form or with <a href="SERVLET" > link </a>

Answer (score 0):

First one is definitely wrong.

`<c:choose>` must have one or more `<c:when>` tags and optionally a `<c:otherwise>` tag nested inside.

`<c:if>` is a single standalone construct.

What is return value of `Session.getLogStat()`? If it is a string `"true"` or `"false"`, then [`Boolean.valueOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#valueOf(java.lang.String)) is correct, but that seems unlikely. Perhaps you meant it as a `null` test?

Anyway, you should use `<c:otherwise>` and `<c:out>`:

```
<c:choose>
  <c:when test="${Session.getLogStat() != null}">
    <c:out value="${Session.getLogStat()}"/>
  </c:when>
  <c:otherwise>
    <a href="login">login</a>
  </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

I would normally collapse that to look like a multi-way `if` statement, which in this case is a simple `if-else` statement:

```
<c:choose><c:when test="${Session.getLogStat() != null}">
  <c:out value="${Session.getLogStat()}"/>
</c:when><c:otherwise>
  <a href="login">login</a>
</c:otherwise></c:choose>
```